# how to center fb:like

Tags: facebook-like

I used this fb like tag

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/favoritebibleverses" send="false" width="300" height="30" show_faces="false" font="" ></fb:like>
```

and I wanted to center it's content.

I've tried these but nothing works properly

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/favoritebibleverses" send="false" width="300" height="30" show_faces="false" font="" text-align="center" ></fb:like>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/favoritebibleverses" send="false" width="300" height="30" show_faces="false" font="" style='text-align:center;' ></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to encapsulate the code in a `div` in order for it to work. Center the `div` and the content contained inside will be centered as a result. I believe that fb:like results in an `iframe` being created which prevents it from being centered without a surrounding `div`.

Alternatively, you may also use the `<center></center>` tags in order to center the content.

Comment: I've tried, and that's working fine if you assign a width on the fb:like tag. another problem is, I must not declare a width to that tag because the width is dynamically changing

Comment: According to the FB developer documentation, the sizes should already be static: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). I don't believe that the sizing is dynamic.

Comment: ok i got it. What I mean dynamic is the text that will display :). If I declare a width, the text that won't fit on it will go to the next line. I think I'm going to follow what you suggested